# Arrow on Activity (AOA) Network Diagram

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, industrial-engineering

I have question-related to industrial management, actually, it is a problem on **arrow on activity network diagram**. I tried to solve the question my self, below are the images. If I did any mistake kindly let me know.

Question:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate activity H should start from the end of activity G.

otherwise you are stating that the duplicate of H can only start once H is completed...

The duplicate of activity K starts from the end of activity F.

When checking these diagrams, you just have to read the story in the diagram back to match the information in the table. If you list some of those paths you find you have:

ABEGHIJ

ABEGHHMN

ABCFKL

ABCFKKMN

And that is the issue, this is what you should have:

ABEGHMN and ABCFKMN

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually the activity M is dependent on H and K. When h is complete and k is complete then i can start M. But you are suggesting what i understand -> start activity M when G and F are completed

Comment: @saadBinZahoor no, I did not suggest that, re-read the answer.

Comment: ok, d is actually a dummy activity. Secondly, let say if i start activity M from the end of activity G and end of activity F. Doesn't it means that activity M is staring after the end of activity   G and F? But in question it says M can only start after K and H are completed.

Comment: @saadBinZahoor **read the answer**. The dummy H starts when G finishes (as stated in the answer) and M can start once H is complete. Same for K.

Comment: So should i make the diagram like this https://ibb.co/fYzxgwJ

Comment: @saadBinZahoor Do as I suggested and check the story back to the table. I am not checking a new diagram for you.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your time.